# Смена цвета блока при прокрутке страницы вниз

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Подскажите почему не работает код.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 100;){
            $(".menu_top").css("background-color","black")
        };
    });
```

Суть вот в чем, при прокрутке страницы вниз на 100px, цвет блока должен меняться на черный, но этого не происходит.

Comment: уберите точку с запятой в условии if($(window).scrollTop() > 100;)

Comment: Точно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убери из условия `;`

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
        $(".menu_top").css("background-color","black")
    };
});
```