# Цвет фона при скроле

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброго времени суток!
Есть один вопрос к знатакам..
Сделал я фиксированое меню с якорями, но есть проблема:
Когда я скролю вниз, у меня к прозрачному меню, то есть **начальное меню** в шапке (на слайдере, если точнее быть),  прописывается **фон** синего цвета.
Но, когда я перезагружаю страницу, у меня фон опять прозрачного фона, хотя я нахожусь не на начальной секции (header), а, например, секция `resume`.

> Вопрос: как реализовать прикрепление синего фона, если user будет делать релоад (reload) страницы на конкретном `якоре` (не в начальной позиции, где прозрачный фон шапки) и `js` будет добавлять `css свойство` этого же синего фона?

Возможно есть готовые скрипты, пока не нашел.. решил спросить здесь, возможно кто-то уже такое делал при верстке.
Вот код:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if($(window).scrollTop() < 300){
  $("#ap-head").css("background","transparent")
 }
 else {
  $("#ap-head").css("background","linear-gradient(to right, #01aed9, 
#01cec7)")
 }
});
```

Вот css:

```
#ap-head{
  z-index: 99;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #01aed9, #01cec7);
  line-height: 1;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Смена цвета блока при прокрутке страницы вниз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765639/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7)

Comment: Это почти то.. но он не до конца реализован

Comment: @Air Посмотрите вопрос еще раз, это не одно и то же что и вопрос что вы нашли здесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы это делаете при `$(window).scroll(function(){`. И то же самое должны сделать при загрузке страницы. То есть при `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if($(window).scrollTop() < 300){
  $("#ap-head").css("background","transparent")
 }
 else {
  $("#ap-head").css("background","linear-gradient(to right, #01aed9, #01cec7)");
 }
});
```

Comment: Супер! То, что надо!
Спасибо большое, вопрос закрыт.